# Getting the device language for a Phonegap application

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, globalization

I'm developing an html5/JqueryMobile/Phonegap app. I have to detect the device language to redirect to a specific html. I'm trying to use Phonegap's `navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage`. On an iOS device it works fine.

The code below detects the language "onDeviceReady" and performs the redirect. This code should be universal for iOS and Android but when I try it on an Android device it doesn't work. The screen freezes. What might cause this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Language</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {

            navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
                                                         function (language)
                                                         {

                                                         if(language.value == "it")
                                                         {window.location.replace("index_it.html");}
                                                         else if (language.value == "ar")
                                                         {window.location.replace("index_ar.html");}
                                                         else 
                                                         {window.location.replace("index_en.html");}},
                                                         function ()
                                                         {
                                                         alert('Error getting language\n');
                                                         }
                                                         );
        }


        </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here, is that language received from Android will have different format, for example instead of Russian with code ru it will return русский